# How to display response in Xml format?

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

I want to display in console the response from request in pretty Xml format, I write code but console displays nothing.
What I want from project is: there some Xml requests (they should work step by step), if (for example) result from first (checkPaymentRequisites) request is equal from 0 and status == 3, then send (go to) second (addOfflinePayment) request. Below codes:

Main method:

```
public static string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string xml)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var xmlResponce = XmlToResponce(responseStream);
        if (xmlResponce.Providers.checkPaymentRequisites.Payment.result == 0 && xmlResponce.Providers.checkPaymentRequisites.Payment.status == 3)
        {
            xml=Requests.addOfflinePayment();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something wrong");
        }
        string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        return responseStr;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Responses:

```
//Responses
//checkPaymentRequisites
private static Responses.Response XmlToResponce (Stream stream)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Responses.Response));
    var xmlResponce = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream) as Responses.Response;
    return xmlResponce;
}

//addOfflinePayment
private static Responses.ResponseOff XmlToResOff(Stream stream)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Responses.ResponseOff));
    var xmlResponce = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream) as Responses.ResponseOff;
    return xmlResponce;
}
```

Diplaying to console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = Requests.checkPaymentRequisites();
    var xml = postXMLData(url, str);
    Console.WriteLine(xml);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I tried some copy-past from other place of code to other place )))) (stupid things), no result

Comment: You want to add a print method to the class xmlResponce.

Comment: @jdweng and how to send second request after successful response from first and also get response from second request?

Comment: A Request/Response makes a connection and the connection closes and is disposed when complete.  So you must create a new request.

Comment: Already I have 2 requests but I dont know how to call and where to call the second request after sccessfully responce from first

Comment: The 2nd should be the same as first except the http header may be different and the body (contents) will be different.  The only headers you have Content Type and Content Length.  The bytes are in the body.